# change resolution using python on mac os

Tags: python, macos

What I want to do is use python to change the display resolution on Mac OSX. As an example, my current display resolution is 1920x1200 and I want to change it to 1600x1000. I know that you can get the width/height using AppKit import NSScreen. However, I can't find any references if AppKit supports resolution change. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for mac:

```
import AppKit
[(screen.frame().size.width, screen.frame().size.height)
    for screen in AppKit.NSScreen.screens()]
```

Comment: It didn't work. I tried replacing the width and height to 1600, 1000 and it does nothing. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: That's weird. I know that this isn't directly what you're looking for but check this out for reference: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19043?locale=en_US

Comment: What I wanted to do is set the display resolution programmatically.

Comment: Why programmatically